# If $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty}g(x)\,dx$ converge absolutely, must $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)g(x)\,dx$ converges?

Tags: analysis

> If $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$ and $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}g(x)\,dx$ converge absolutely, must $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)g(x)\,dx$ converges?

Is this true? I tried to prove by using mean value theorem of integrals, but failed.

Comment: No. Choose $f(x) = g(x) = \frac 1{\sqrt x}$ on $(0,1)$ and zero elsewhere. However, the answer is yes if one of them is bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $f(x) = g(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \chi_{(0,1)}$. That should give you a counterexample

Answer (score 2):

One could be lured into believing your claim, because one might too quickly think that a function $f$ with $\int_0^{\infty}|f(x)|\;dx$ had to approach zero if $x$ tends to infinity. But this is not so, hence a possible counter example may look correspondingly:

- Let $f(x) = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}nI_{\left[n-\frac{1}{n^3},n+\frac{1}{n^3}\right]}(x)$, where $I_M$ is the indicator function for a set $M$.

Basically these are bars around any $n \in \mathbb{N}, n\geq 2$ with height $n$ and base of length $\frac{2}{n^3}$. So, they get higher and higher but also narrower and narrower at the same time.

- Then, you have
  $$\int_0^{\infty}f(x)\;dx = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n\frac{2}{n^3}= 2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2} < \infty$$
- But, squaring gives
  $$\int_0^{\infty}(f(x))^2\;dx = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n^2\frac{2}{n^3}= 2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n} = \infty$$